# deleted Item place in ArrayAdapter in my ListView left empty

Tags: java, android, animation

I used animated for deleting Item in ArrayAdapter in my ListView.
but when i deleted one row, It's place remained empty and lower box was not coverd empty place.[image]

what can i do The lower box to come up and The stick-top box?
what can I do?

```
    listViewHome.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(final AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
            Log.i("@@@@@@", "setOnItemClickListener: " + position);

            view.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(1000).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    Log.i("@@@@@@", "onAnimationEnd: " + position);
                    contacts.remove(position);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

If I don't use animate everything is ok but when I use animate for deleting Its place Item remained empty and lower box was not coverd empty place.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be ok. Another way you can try (which is actually equal with your way) is:

```
adapter.remove(yourArraylist.get(position));
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

If it still not working try this:

```
Object toRemove = adapter.getItem([position]);
adapter.remove(toRemove);
```

This might help [Delete Items android ListView Tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=luxE7oEKiic)